# dependent scope error with stl

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Counter
{
    public:
        Counter()
        {
            totalCount     
        }

        ~Counter()
        {
        }

        bool containsKey(T key)
        {
            map<T, double>::iterator it = counter.find(T);
            if (it == counter.end()) return false;
            return true;
        }

    private:
        map<T, double> counter;
        double totalCount;
};

int main()
{
    Counter<string> table;
    return 0;
}
```

this code doesn't even compile and I can't figure out what's the error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

cmd to compile

```
g++ counter.cpp
```

The error is

```
error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::map<T, double>::iterator’ because ‘std::map<T, double>’ is a dependent scope
```

Comment: I think the error is giving you a very good hint

Comment: `if (…) return false; else return true;` is an anti-pattern. Write `return not …;` instead.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that convention. will make use of it...

Comment: Also, your default constructor won't compile as it is currently...

Answer (score 6):

Compiler knows that T is the name of a type (typename) from your template declaration but it doesn't know if std::map::iterator is a type or something different. So as compiler says you have to add 'typename' before this statement to tell compiler it's a name of a type.

As a summary: change

```
map<T, double>::iterator it = counter.find(T);
```

to

```
typename map<T, double>::iterator it = counter.find(T);
```